# Multiple tables condensed to one row with various totals

Tags: sql-server

We have Applications, which run on Hosts, which have Software on them.

An Application can run on many Hosts. A Host typically has many Software items loaded onto it.

We capture this information with an Application table, and two more tables to capture the relationships, Application-Host, Host-Software.

It is possible, however, that a Host does not have Software. (It might be genuinely empty or we might not have information yet, both need to be highlighted.)

For each Application, I need to count the Hosts having software on them. I cannot find a way to do it.

Assume an Application has 5 Hosts, four of which are connected to Software. One relationship table contains 5 Hosts, the other many instances of 4 Hosts, but the 4 are indirectly connected through the first relationship table.

How can I get the correct answer, 4? Whatever I do I get 5, or the total number of Software items on all hosts.

---

This is what I have so far, including debug code.

```
select distinct
AH.APPLICATION_X_COMPONENT_NAME,
count(case when T.TECH_ITEM_REL_ITCM_CAT = 'Operating System' then 1 end) over      (partition by AH.APPLICATION_X_COMPONENT_NAME) as NoOfOpsys,
x.APPLICATION_X_COMPONENT_NAME,
x.HOST_COMPONENT_NAME,
x.NoHostsWithTIR
from dbo.CTO_TechnologyItemRelease as T

inner join dbo.CTOR_HOST_TECHITEMRELEASE as HT
on HT.TECH_ITEM_RELEASE_COMP_ID = T.TechnologyItemReleaseComponent

inner join dbo.CTOR_APPLICATIONX_HOST as AH
on AH.HOST_COMPONENT_ID = HT.HOST_COMPONENT_ID

inner join
(
select distinct
AH2.APPLICATION_X_COMPONENT_NAME,
AH2.HOST_COMPONENT_NAME,
count(case when HT2.HOST_COMPONENT_NAME is not null then 1 end) over (partition by AH2.APPLICATION_X_COMPONENT_NAME, HT2.HOST_COMPONENT_NAME) as NoHostsWithTIR
from dbo.CTOR_APPLICATIONX_HOST as AH2

inner join dbo.CTOR_HOST_TECHITEMRELEASE as HT2
on HT2.HOST_COMPONENT_NAME = AH2.HOST_COMPONENT_NAME
)
as x on x.APPLICATION_X_COMPONENT_NAME = AH.APPLICATION_X_COMPONENT_NAME

order by AH.APPLICATION_X_COMPONENT_NAME
```

Data:

```
App table
App_ID     App_Name
A0001      Application_1
A0002      Application_2
A0003      Application_3
A0004      Application_4

App-Host table
App_ID     App_Name              Host_ID  Host_Name
A0001      Application_1         H0001    Host_1
A0002      Application_2         H0001    Host_1
A0002      Application_2         H0002    Host_2
A0002      Application_2         H0003    Host_3
A0002      Application_2         H0004    Host_4
A0003      Application_3         H0005    Host_5
A0004      Application_4         H0002    Host_2
A0004      Application_4         H0006    Host_6

Host-TI table
Host_ID    Host_Name   TI_ID    TI_Name
H0001      Host_1      T0001    MS SQL Server 2005 SP1
H0001      Host_1      T0002    MS Windows Server 2008
H0002      Host_2      T0002    Red Hat Enterprise Linux 3
H0003      Host_3      T0002    MS Windows Server 2008
H0003      Host_3      T0003    Oracle Database Server 9i 9.2    
H0005     Host_5      T0001    MS SQL Server 2005 SP1
H0006      Host_6      T0004    Tivoli Storage Manager 5.2

TI table
TI_ID    TI_Name                          TI_Type
T0001    MS SQL Server 2005 SP1           Software Product
T0002    MS Windows Server 2008           Operating System
T0003    Red Hat Enterprise Linux 3       Operating System
T0003    Oracle Database Server 9i 9.2    Software Product
T0004    Tivoli Storage Manager 5.2       Software Product
```

The required output

```
App Name          Operating System count        Hosts with Tech Items
Application_1     1                             1       
Application_2     3                             3
Application_3     0                             1
Application_4     1                             2
```

The crucial line is Application_2 having 3 hosts with tech items. I can only get a 4 in this position and my Operating System count goes on the blink frequently.

Comment: Your question will do far better including a schema diagram and some sample data. Even better would be do setup a mock sqlfiddle as well. Finally, try to show what you attempted to solve this yourself so far.

Comment: Oh, yes - and don't forget to show an example of the output you're after based on the sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database design seems seriously fubar'd, so the data appear to be inconsistent:

These rows appear to contradict one another:

```
H0001      Host_1      T0002    MS Windows Server 2008
H0002      Host_2      T0002    Red Hat Enterprise Linux 3
```

as do these:

```
T0003    Red Hat Enterprise Linux 3       Operating System
T0003    Oracle Database Server 9i 9.2    Software Product
```

I'm gonna assume that the data is invalid, and that the correct data is along the lines in the [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/87832/6).

Under that assumption this code will get you what you need:

```
select a.app_ID, a.app_name, 
  (select Count(*) 
     from apphost ah
       inner join hostti ht on ah.host_id = ht.host_id
       inner join ti on ht.ti_id=ti.ti_id
   where ti_type = 'Operating System'
     and ah.app_id = a.app_id) as OSCount,
  (select Count(distinct ah.host_id) 
     from apphost ah
       inner join hostti ht on ah.host_id = ht.host_id
   where ah.app_id = a.app_id) as HostWithSoftwareCount
from App a
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
select a.name, COUNT(*)
from application a
join application_host ah on (a.id = ah.application)
join host h on (h.id = ah.host)
where exists (select top 1 1 from host_software hs where hs.host = ah.host)
group by a.name
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c4bbb/2

Answer (score 0):

I agree [with @SWeko](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18253085/297408) on the point of inconsistency in your data samples and here's also my take on the problem:

```
SELECT
  ap.App_Name,
  OperatingSystemCount = COUNT(ti.TI_ID),
  HostsWithTechItems   = COUNT(DISTINCT ah.Host_ID)
FROM
  App AS ap
  LEFT JOIN
    AppHost AS ah
    INNER JOIN HostTI AS ht ON ah.Host_ID = ht.Host_ID
    LEFT JOIN TI AS ti ON ht.TI_ID = ti.TI_ID AND ti.TI_Type = 'Operating System'
  ON ap.App_ID = ah.App_ID
GROUP BY
  ap.App_Name
;
```

A SQL Fiddle demo for this query can be found here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/677ae/3

Note that when counting operating systems, the query doesn't recognise the fact that some of them may be installed on the same host: in that case, each instance would be counted. If you actually meant to count *hosts with operating systems* instead, you would need to change the above query by replacing `COUNT(ti.TI_ID)` with something like

```
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ti.TI_ID IS NOT NULL THEN ah.Host_ID END)
```